# Base Class Of Evil -

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Watching Sean Parent's talk on the ["Base class of evil"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil), I looked at some of my own code and code at work. And when I try to apply Sean Parents idea to them I'm left with two options from what I can see. Expose my member variables, or just have the function callback to to the class's member variable.

```
void draw(const Foo &foo)
{
   foo.draw();
}

// or

void draw(const Foo &foo)
{
   // access foo's members to draw
}
```

I don't like the idea of either of these, on one hand I have exposed members that shouldn't really be so scrap that one. And the other hand I seem to have created a whole bunch of functions that seem to just do indirection. Which seems a little messy.

Now I liked the talk and do generally hate these structures that get generated, but I'm not sure I can convince people at work that writing 100's of functions that just seem to apply indirection is worthwhile.

Have I missed something?

Comment: You could improve your question by adding links to the original talk.

Comment: or explain shortly what was spoken there

Comment: IMO you really can't make this a true general talk. Fictional examples will push you to A or to B but real-world is seldom so clear. For 2nd case I would avoid to expose internal state but for 1st one you may end with 20 methods that just forward to something else (with high coupling between classes). You may also introduce a 2nd object (private to Foo and then with full access to its state). Moreover you also have non member functions (just in case). C++ is pretty flexible but...I'd judge this case by case.

Comment: If it makes sense to be a member function, make it a member function instead of exposing data members. If using the class's public interface, a free function is probably a good bet. Anyway, Concepts will help a lot in this regard when they're ready and right now, Boost.TypeErasure is one library for doing away with a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: The answer to give really depends on the context.  You could, for example, create a new "decorator" class that has functions to draw either or both of them so they aren't too tightly coupled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `friend`.  You're implementing an external function which conceptually *belongs* to the class, it's a perfectly sane use of the keyword and doesn't inappropriately expose anything.

Mr. Parent uses `friend` inline which I had no idea was possible.  He never touched on it so I didn't catch it at first.  I had to prove to myself that actually works...

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo 
{
  public:
    Foo() : val(5) {}

    friend void draw(Foo const & a)
    { printf ("%d\n", a.val); } // You can implement friends inline?!

  private:
    int val;

};

int main (void)
{
  Foo my_foo;
  draw(my_foo);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seems like the best way forward.